# Trichain: Three Times Ten

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is a [**Trichain**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102673/trichain-introduction) puzzle. The rules of **Trichain** are as follows:

> 1. Numbers must be white, and match the size of their white islands.
> 2. Each white island can only contain at most one number. Some white islands may have no numbers.
> 3. Black squares must be part of L-trominoes.
> 4. Black L-trominoes cannot be adjacent horizontally or vertically, but all of them must be connected diagonally. In other words, one standing on a black square must be able to visit any other black square via Chess King's moves, stepping on black squares only.

Here is an example **Trichain** puzzle, and its solution:

> [image] [image]

Here is the real **Trichain**. Go for it!

> [image]

Comment: [w l and I found that your puzzle has at least 2 solutions.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55763686#55763686)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [image]
>  The bottom right has 2 possible solutions.

Comment: Yikes, thanks for catching that. I tried so hard to make total uniqueness but that one slipped my eye :(