# Trichain: Tetrachain

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is a [**Trichain**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102673/trichain-introduction) puzzle. The rules of **Trichain** are as follows:

> 1. Numbers must be white, and match the size of their white islands.
> 2. Each white island can only contain at most one number. Some white islands may have no numbers.
> 3. Black squares must be part of L-trominoes.
> 4. Black L-trominoes cannot be adjacent horizontally or vertically, but all of them must be connected diagonally. In other words, one standing on a black square must be able to visit any other black square via Chess King's moves, stepping on black squares only.

Here is an example **Trichain** puzzle, and its solution:

> [image] [image]

Here is the real **Trichain**. The only clues this time are 4s. Go for it!

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Overview

To be completely honest, solving this puzzle was mostly trial and error for me. I initially focused on the top left corner and throughout the entirety of the solution path I focused primarily on testing how the diagonal relationships impacted the surrounding areas.

##### The Top Row

I spent a fair amount of time here, initially focused on the top left corner with a setup involving:

> [image: Screenshot of the initial thoughts.]

However, as time passed, and I became more and more frustrated with it, I had a realization that I was focused on one way and needed to try something new. I started focusing on ways to create the first 4 in the top corner, ultimately settling on the following as I placed and erased blocks along the top to *simulate* placing the L and what the impact below it was:

> [image: Screenshot of the solved top row.]

##### Closing the Obvious

Certainly not obvious to everyone, but considering I had tried many solutions in the area by painting and erasing, I knew based on the top row that the diagonal connections would only support one configuration:

> [image: Screenshot of the closed middle left 4.]

However, since I still had the right wall to solve, my suspicions of the lower left corner had to be validated by closing the right side.

##### The Right Side

Here, I started in the bottom right corner closing the right side with trial and error while taking into account the impact of the middle and left:

> [image: Screenshot of the solved right side.]

##### Wrapping Up

Solving the right side confirmed my suspicions of the lower left corner due to the obvious connections required in the center:

> [image: Screenshot of the populated center.]

The rest was as simple as following the diagonal connections:

> [image: Screenshot of the completed puzzle.]

Comment: That will get you a (spoiler warning!) [checkmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDDvq.png)!