# How do I construct a Japanese-style "grid deduction" puzzle?

Tags: grid-deduction, puzzle-creation

Logic puzzles like Nurikabe, Slitherlink, and Battleships -- the ones we call [grid-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) puzzles -- can be a lot of fun.

How do I go about constructing them? What's the best strategy for making these puzzles interesting and still uniquely solvable?

Comment: Great answer, but this has been [asked](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48458/5373) *twice* [before](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/61376/5373). Maybe better to link all the duplicates together, and maybe consider merging them to get all these nice answers in one place?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Good catch! They didn't appear in the suggested duplicates when I was asking. A merge would be the best solution, but I'm not sure which of the three questions is best to treat as the 'primary': I think there would be upsides and downsides to all three.

Comment: In my (unbiased? :-P ) opinion, [mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/61376/5373) is the best primary: the question is a bit longer / more detailed, and answer quality doesn't matter since they'll all be together anyway. [boboquack's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/48458/5373) might (?) be worth leaving separately, since it's slightly different, asking for specific strategies posted in separate answers, rather than a general how-to guide like my and your questions.